# "flash" is not defined in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I'm using the regular `flash.utils.Dictionary` for a dictionary of source objects, and a custom implementation `flos.utils.Dictionary` that has extended functionality like retrieving the length of the dictionary and automatically removing keys when their value is set to undefined.

I'm getting these errors during compilation:

- "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Dictionary."
- "1120: Access of undefined property flash."
- "1120: Access of undefined property flash."

Those three errors are occurring for each of the private variables declared in the code below.  I'm importing my custom dictionary, so I'm using the fully-qualified name when targeting the built-in dictionary `flash.utils.Dictionary`, but it seems to think that the `flash` namespace is undefined.

```
package flos.system.binding 
{
    import flos.utils.Dictionary;

    internal class BindingDictionary
    {
        private var targetBindings:flash.utils.Dictionary = new flash.utils.Dictionary(); //Dictionary of targets, containing dictionaries of bound target properties, containing the source/propertyName pair that the target is bound to.
        private var sourceBindings:flash.utils.Dictionary = new flash.utils.Dictionary(); //Dictionary of sources, containing Dictionaries of bound source properties, containing Binding instances that determine which targets/properties the source property is bound to.

        public function BindingDictionary()
        {
        }
```

FYI, this internal class used to be a private class declared in the same file as a Bindings class, outside the package at the bottom of the file.  I was getting a runtime error #1007 "Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. at Binding$iinit()", when I tried to call a static member of the Binding class.  All the classes had constructors and I could not figure out what was wrong, so I moved the classes into separate files, and that's when I ran into these compilation errors instead.

Comment: I thought that by declaring the variable with the fully-qualified name, I wouldn't have to use an explicit import statement, but apparently I do.  The reason I didn't want to use the import statement for the built-in dictionary class, is because I didn't want to have an ambiguous reference to Dictionary throughout the rest of the class, which I want to use my implementation of Dictionary.  I may be forced to have explicit imports for both, and use the fully qualified name throughout the class to avoid the ambiguous references.

I shouldn't need an import when using fully-qualified names.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that importing a class is absolutely required in AS3, unlike AS2, if you want to use it, unless it's declared in the same package as the class in which you're trying to use it: [Packages and Namespaces - Importing Packages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f92)

You must have an import statement for the class itself or the package that contains it.  One of:

- import flash.utils.Dictionary
- import flash.utils.*;

That means the behavior I'm seeing was by design.  When two classes from external packages are imported and have the same name, there is no way around the requirement of using the fully qualified names to disambiguate them everywhere the name is used throughout the class, despite the maintenance difficulty.

I guess I was thinking of AS3's `import` statement like C#'s `using` statement, trying to make one dictionary the default to avoid using fully qualified names on the most frequently referenced class, while just using the the fully-qualified name for the other class in one or two lines.  In AS3, you must import both, deal with the ambiguous references, and use fully-qualified names on every reference to both classes.

Comment: Avoid using the `flash.utils.*` import. Depending on compile type, it could include *all* classes from that package in your build rather than just the one needed. Just adds to the final file size